# Error 404 sending a JSON with WebClient.UploadValues

Tags: c#, json.net, http-status-code-404, webclient

I'm trying to make a call with WebClient.UploadValues, but I'm having a little problem.

It works fine this way:

```
NameValueCollection parametros = new NameValueCollection();
parametros.Add("idUsuarioSolicitante", "24");
parametros.Add("localColeta", "3");
parametros.Add("requisicaoDTOListaJSON", "1");

var retorno = conexao.UploadValues("SincronizacaoAPI/SincronizarRequisicao", parametros);
```

But when I put my JSON param I got a 404 error:

```
NameValueCollection parametros = new NameValueCollection();
parametros.Add("idUsuarioSolicitante", "24");
parametros.Add("localColeta", "3");
parametros.Add("requisicaoDTOListaJSON", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
     TransformadorDTOEntidade.GetRequisicaoSinc(requisicaoPendenteLista)));

var retorno = conexao.UploadValues("SincronizacaoAPI/SincronizarRequisicao", parametros);
```

Details:

Signature of the method I'm trying to call:

```
public string SincronizarRequisicao(int idUsuarioSolicitante, int localColeta,
        string requisicaoDTOListaJSON)
{
    ...
}
```

(I'm calling a controller from another controller, two diferent projects. .NET Framework 4.5.)

Comment: Hola amigo, Can you share the URL that you have request to? Edit: I mean API route url

Comment: http://localhost:PORT/SincronizacaoAPI/SincronizarRequisicao?...

Comment: I have build some dummy example but it passes to the api function. Can you check the variable: "requisicaoPendenteLista" is null or not?

Comment: Nope! It has something like 6000 items...

Comment: Can you try with less items like 3-5. You may exceed the request length.

Comment: Nice! With something like 40 it works... But the "idUsuarioSolicitante" is null in the destiny. What now?

Comment: Hmm interesting. By the way, idUsuarioSolicitante cannot be null. Because it's integer. You mean zero I guess. I suggest you to obtain these three variables in one object.

Comment: My bad. "idUsuarioSolicitante" is ok, the null one is "requisicaoDTOListaJSON". The JSON guy.

Comment: Then I deserve the accepted answer :)

Comment: Heh! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with less items like 3-5. You may exceed the request length.
In order to increase the request length check this SO answer:

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853785/6322573)